# Wordwrap for Custom ListBoxes Added Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a custom ListBoxItem that I am trying to add programmatically to a ListBox, and I want the contents of the item to wrap.

Here is the custom ListBoxItem:

```
class PresetListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
{
    public uint[] preset;

    public PresetListBoxItem(uint[] preset = null, string content = "N/A")
        : base()
    {
        this.preset = preset;
        this.Content = content;
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="sortingBox" Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="150" MaxWidth="150" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" Margin="3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the code that does the adding:

```
PresetListBoxItem item = new PresetListBoxItem();
item.preset = new uint[] { };
item.Content = "This is a test of an extended line of text.";
sortingBox.Items.Add(item);
```

When I run the code, the item gets added to the box, but the border doesn't show up at all and it doesn't wrap the lines.

I've looked all over SO and Google for the answer, and I've used both ListBoxes and ListViews, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListBoxItem` is just a Container for the Content respectively Item. If you want to use your own `ListBoxItem` override the Template of the Container not the Item. Then for the right binding in `TextBlock` you have to bind to the `Content` property of your PresetListBoxItem.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PresetListBoxItem">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" Margin="3">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PresetListBoxItem}}"
                                   TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But I think it's not the best way. Why you derive from `ListBoxItem`? If you don't do this your XAML would be instantly okay.

```
item.Text = "This is a test of an extended line of text.";

class PresetListBoxItem
{
    public uint[] preset;
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public PresetListBoxItem(uint[] preset = null, string content = "N/A")
      : base()
    {
        this.preset = preset;
        this.Text = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a custom class that derives from ListBoxItem because I need to get the associated uint[] when someone selects that item in the ListBox. The only other way I can think of doing it is to somehow tie an index to a List with the ListBoxItem, and that just seems like an error prone way of doing things.

Comment: You will find your class with uint[] in the DataContext of ListBoxItem.